# jsf application not supporting data entry from multiple log ins

Tags: jsf

This is a very simple question for which i present my apologies but i need expert guidance on it since my knowledge is way too primitive that i don't know what to search on google to solve my problem.

I have developed a simple data entry application in jsf which gives users a form to enter data then generated one pdf report on the basis of data. The application works fine but when more then one user simultaneously tries to enter data, users can't do that, only one user at a time can enter data.

Please give me some idea what should I should study and on what subject I need to do the research.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more detail, e.g. paste the jsf template and backing bean code. What is the exact error for the second user?

Answer (score 0):

That can only mean that you're holding some request/session scoped information in static variables or in application scoped variables which would then be shared among all users in the entire application. Apparently you've either awarely or unawarely programmed some static/application wide lock which prevents other users from using the same application.

It's not possible to give a targeted answer as to how to fix this problem as you didn't show any code, but you should start looking at static variables and application scoped variables and investigate if they aren't incorrectly holding request/session scoped data. If they do, then you should make them non-static and/or request/session scoped instead.

Comment: thanks alot. i will scrutinize my code in the ligth of ur guidance and get back to u with some solid clue. atleast now i have some idea what i need to look for in my code